# Easiest way to find divisors of 60 in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Other than hardcoding or using the Math module, Is there any way I can find divisors of 60 in Ruby on Rails. Any helper methods/regular expression that I can make use of? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Might need more context.

Comment: I need to display divisors of 60 in a dropdown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to achieve this would be to create a list of numbers between 1 and 60, and then only select the ones that divide 60 with no remainder.

To expand on SteveTurczyn's answer, we can do:

```
(1..60).select { |n| 60 % n == 0 }
```

The `(1..60)` part creates an enumerator (which in this case we can think of as an array of the numbers between 1 and 60).

Then you want to take this array, and select only the elements are divisors of 60.

We can use the modulus operator `%`, which gives us the remainder left over when we divide a number by another (e.g., `5 % 2` returns `1`). Of course, if there is no remainder, then we know that the number divided cleanly, and is therefore a divisor of that number (i.e., if `a % b == 0`, then b is a divisor of a).

So what we want to do, is use the above as a criteria for selecting elements out of the array of numbers between 1 and 60, which we are able to do with the [Array#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) method.

If we have something, like an array (technically, I think, an [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html)), we can use #select and a block to pull out only the elements that satisfy whatever criteria we specify in the block.

The `{ |n| 60 % n == 0 }` is the block we are passing to #select, which will return true whenever `60 % n` is `0` (each `n` is an element from the array of numbers 1 through 60). `Array#select` only returns the elements in the array for which the block evaluates to true- which is how SteveTurczyn's solution works.

Comment: You can half the number of comparisons because no number greater than half of 60 can be a divisor of it (apart from 60 itself).

Comment: "The (1..60) part creates an enumerator". Almost. A `Range`, actually, that includes `Enumerable`.

Comment: @Pavling even more so, each discovered divisor actually discovers two, if you also get the quotient. That makes it possible to only iterate up to `sqrt(n)` inclusively. The algorithm becomes less concise, though.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I get to learn something today too. :)

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the array of divisors

```
(1..60).select { |n| 60 % n == 0}
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60]
```

Answer (score 1):

For small numbers it's okay to use the brute force search, but for large numbers this approach doesn't suite. You can speed up your method significantly by selecting divisors as pairs.

Some examples with benchmarks:

```rb
require 'benchmark'

n = 10_000_000

def brute_force(n)
  (1..n).select { |i| n % i == 0 }
end

def faster_way(n)
  (1..Math.sqrt(n)).each_with_object([]) { |i, arr| (n % i).zero? && arr << i && n/i != i && arr << n/i }
end

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { brute_force(n) }
  x.report { faster_way(n) }
end

# Benchmark output
       user     system      total        real
   0.799491   0.001417   0.800908 (  0.802341)
   0.000580   0.000002   0.000582 (  0.000581)
```

As you can see the second approach is `1376` times faster for `n = 10_000_000`.